# Setting a constant char* in a header file?

Tags: c++, c

If I wanted to set a private, constant character array in a header file, how could you do that?  Compilers don't seem to like it.. Here is what I tried.

```
static const char *foo = "SomeCharArray";
```

Comment: That's perfectly valid C. What did your compiler say that makes you think it didn't like it?

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I'm curious as to why you removed the c++ tag.  This question applies equally to both c and c++.

Comment: @nmichaels: It's valid C in an implementation file; not in a header.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I tested the follwing in gcc and it didn't complain. static const char foo[]="Some String"; static const char *bar="Another String";

Comment: @PigBen: Because in C++ it'd be `static std::string foo("SomeCharArray");`

Comment: @Billy: It is perfectly legal to use memory in a header. Bad practice doesn't equal invalid.

Comment: @Billy, you seem to be saying that it's not possible to declare a const char* in C++, which is plainly false. Even if there are better alternatives to such a practice, you can't say it doesn't exist or that Kin didn't really mean to ask about C++.

Comment: @Billy: It could be, but that doesn't change the fact the question still applies to c++ as much is it does to c.

Comment: @PigBen: The same could be said of most any C question. That doesn't mean every C question should have both tags. In C++ using `static` for this purpose is deprecated; therefore it's not a C++ question. But since you seem so adamant about this it does at least need the C tag.

Comment: @Billy, this use of `static` will not be deprecated anymore with the upcoming C++ standard. And just because it's deprecated now doesn't mean that Kin didn't want to ask about it in regard to C++ anyway. People are allowed to ask about things they shouldn't do, *especially* if they don't know that they shouldn't do it. Anyway, thanks for putting back the tag.

Comment: @Billy: I clicked the rollback because I mistakenly thought the C tag was on there to begin with, sorry about that.

Comment: @Rob: Never said he couldn't ask. Just that a C++ tag was inappropriate.

Comment: So what's the verdict?  Since the answers indicate that the code worked form them, why is kin having a problem with his compiler?  Is kin using command line switches that tell the compiler to reject that code?

Answer (score 3):

Use `extern` keyword in the following way.

```
// myfile.h
extern const char* foo;

// myfile.cpp
const char* foo = "SomeCharArray";
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code compiles fine:

consty.h:

```
static const char *foo = "SomeCharArray";
```

consty.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "consty.h"
int main()
{
    printf ("Hi %s\n", foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that any file that includes `consty.h` will get its own copy of foo. Other people have described the proper way to share global variables with `extern`.

Answer (score 0):

file.h:

```
extern const char* foo;
#define FOO_DATA "SomeCharDATA"
```

file.c:

```
const char *foo = FOO_DATA;
```

Comment: If you're going to do that you might as well just use FOO_DATA directly.

Comment: Not really, @Billy. If you use `FOO_DATA` directly, then you can't change its value, whereas if you use `foo`, you can make `foo` point at some other char instead.

Comment: @Billy You are right, but not all linkers search for identical strings and remove them.

Comment: The issue with this is that you get the worst of both worlds. You pollute other translation units with the macro, AND you have to deal with the complexities of linkage. Either use the macro everywhere or don't use it at all (and define it in the translation unit where `foo` is defined only)

Answer (score 0):

Given that this:

```
static const char *foo = "SomeCharArray";
```

is a perfectly valid C (even in an header file) I think you should ask yourself why you want this in an header!

If you need a variable scope to be restricted to a .c file just put the declaration in that file. If you find yourself in need of sharing *private* data between two .c files, you probably have not split the functions and data in the most appropriate way across your files.